# Can the molecule CH2(ONa)2 be stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbonyl-compounds

[image: Structure]

While studying about Cannizzaro reaction, it came to my mind as a wild thought what if this HCH(ONa)(ONa) molecule could pop out in some step of this reaction (not giving much details about how I thought it as it would be irrelevant). Then I thought this molecule might have some problem with stability. The $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized carbon might have some have problem with spacing two -ONa groups close together.

So, is this molecule stable or not? If not why?

Comment: I guess it's sort of follow-up of http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55692/is-the-compound-ch2ohona-possible and answer is similar I guess - it's highly basic intermediate.

Comment: Oxygen and sodium will hardly form a covalent bond.

Answer (score 2):

The species you are proposing would be a [methanediol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanediol) dianion (CH<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub><sup>2–</sup>) with two sodium cations “attached” to it in some way, depending on the nature of the solvent.

While methanediol can indeed readily form an anion, with a pKa of 13.3, I find no mention of the dianion or any measure (or prediction) of the second pKa of methanediol.